How to count the number of groups of events that are more than 20 minutes from each other?
Consider the following events:
+---------------------+------------+
| S                   | D          |
+---------------------+------------+
| 2024-07-21 07:01:48 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 07:01:49 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 07:02:03 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 07:09:50 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 07:10:18 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 07:10:40 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:12:01 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:12:18 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:12:28 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:12:57 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:13:21 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:19:59 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:20:28 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 12:20:42 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 17:03:37 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 17:04:17 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 17:04:28 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 17:04:40 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:41:51 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:42:30 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:42:32 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:55:22 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:55:31 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:55:59 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 19:56:07 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 20:04:12 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 20:04:48 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 20:05:01 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-21 20:05:19 | 2024-07-21 |
| 2024-07-22 07:07:56 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:07:57 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:08:23 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:08:40 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:08:51 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:16:09 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:16:44 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:17:06 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 07:17:07 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:15:24 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:15:34 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:15:53 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:16:05 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:25:11 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:26:00 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 12:26:14 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:08:46 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:08:55 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:09:23 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:09:49 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:10:33 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:11:06 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:18:54 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:19:34 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 15:19:57 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:13:16 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:29:23 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:29:24 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:30:03 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:30:56 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:41:08 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:42:06 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:42:07 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:42:29 | 2024-07-22 |
| 2024-07-22 19:42:34 | 2024-07-22 |
+---------------------+------------+

I want to be able to query for the number of times that groups of events are more than 20 minutes apart from each other.
The above data should produce the following result:
+------------+-------+
| D          | COUNT |
+------------+-------+
| 2024-07-22 |     4 |
| 2024-07-21 |     4 |
+------------+-------+

I started a dbfiddle with the data, but I have no idea how to even start the query.

What does a "group" mean?  At the end of 2024-07-21, you have a series that lasts 24 minutes.  Is that a "group"?  Why?  Are you just looking for "all gaps larger than 20 minutes"?

Shouldn't there be 5 groups for 2024-07-21 as there are groups 07:01:48-07:10:40; 12:12:01-12:20:42; 17:03:37-17:04:40; 19:41:51-19:56:07; 20:04:12-20:05:19

Your expected answer is wrong. count of date 2024-07-21 should be 3. @Simpler

@taxevader 19:56:07 and 20:04:12 are within the 20 minute window.   The check is between each event, not just the first event in a group.  Thanks.

@ArtBindu I'm not sure why your answer is getting 3 for 2024-07-21.  When I use your code in my data, it correctly produces 4.  Thanks for your help.

@TimRoberts, correct.  I'm just looking for gaps greater than 20 minutes.

Use LAG()/LEAD() SQL function to compare with previous/next data.
So, your answer should be:
WITH T AS (
    select D, S, 
    LAG(S) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL order by S) as prev_s
    FROM Events
    order by S
)
SELECT D, 
    count(D) as count 
FROM T
where abs(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(S, prev_s))) > (60*20)
group by D
order by D DESC;


Update query in details
dbfiddle
